# Creating Database using phpMyAdmin in WAMP

Tags: mysql, database, wampserver

I've installed WAMP stack and tried creating databases using phpMyAdmin. But in the Databases section it says 'No Privileges' which means that I have no rights to create database. However it seems possible for me to create, drop data bases using command line. Even when I create a database using command line it's not displayed in phpMyAdmin too.

Also I couldn't create database, tables using php also. Please help me out on this.

Comment: when you login, are you root or another name?  Also, did you specify a mysql username/id during the install process?